# Bolding text in autocomplete-light

Tags: django-autocomplete-light

I was wondering if there is a way to enable bolding of matching results when a user enter search text.  Meaning: if I type appl, the autocomplete possible results should have this behavior.

**appl**e

**appl**ecart

pine**appl**e

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do that, override [choice_html](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#autocomplete_light.autocomplete.base.AutocompleteBase.choice_html) or use a [template autocomplete](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/master/template.html)